# HTML mailer in Outlook showing whitespace

Tags: html, removing-whitespace

I am trying to create HTML mailer which is working fine in almost all the email clients like Gmail, Yahoo, MSN etc. I also want to make sure that it runs fine in Outlook but if I try to send it through Outlook then it adds up some extra white space between table elements which is distorting the complete view.

Here is the link of my mailer:

http://ebinarysolutions.com/thieme/thieme/thieme.html

Comment: Not 100% sure about your whitespace issue but I would recommend that you reduce your image file sizes as they are far too large. Also best practice is to have the width of your email no more than 600px or alternatively fluid width. Here's a great HTML email guide: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I think issue is not related to image size. There is something else which is adding white spaces.

Comment: My comments above were just to try and improve your emails not address the whitespace issue :-)

Comment: The link in this question goes to a domain holding page, so I think it is safe to say this question is abandoned, and can be closed.